# Problem with regex in product name (TPL prestashop 1.6)

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I need put regex `^.*gold|Gold|GOLD.*` in product.tpl (Prestashop 1.6) and check if product name consist gold or Gold or GOLD. If product name consist in product name for example "Anchor blue Gold" then I need create product flag. Is that possible? I try it, but function is not working correctly.

```php
{if (preg_match('^.*gold|gold|GOLD.*', {$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}))}
                <span class="new-box">
                        <span class="zlato-label">GOLD 24K</span>
            {elseif(preg_match('^.*rosegold|Rosegold|ROSEGOLD.*', {$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}))}
                <span class="new-box">
                        <span class="zlato-label">Rose GOLD 24K</span>
            {else}
                <span class="new-box">
                        <span class="new-label">Nothing</span>
            {/if}
```

Comment: I am no expert in regexes nor prestashop, but have you tried putting the alternatives in parentheses like `'^.*(gold|gold|GOLD).*'`, or, probably better, looking for an option which makes the regex case-insensitive?

Comment: OK, I guess this is PHP, where regex declarations are different from usual, so you have to put a delimiter at the start and end of the regex, and after the ending delimiter you can use `i` to make it case-insenstive, so `if (preg_match('/^.*gold.*/i', ` etc. I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Although the documentation says that if you just want to check if a string is contained in another you should use strpos, and there is a case-insensitive version of that: [stripos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

Comment: Another thing... you need to test for "rosegold" before testing for "gold" because "rosegold" contains the string "gold". (And rose gold can't be 24K because that would be pure gold with no copper - perhaps it's a typo for 14K.)